# Comparing each row in 2 arrays to find the same string and modifying another column based on result

Tags: python, loops, pandas, lambda, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing car makes(eg. BMW, Tata, Mercedes-Benz). This is called *makes*. I also have another dataframe containing car models(eg. Mercedes-Benz E Class, BMW 3 series) called *models* .

[image: Makes]
[image: Models]

For each model, I want to find its corresponding make from the **specific makes** I have in the *makes* dataframe, and when the make is found I want it inserted into the corresponding row in the *make* column of the models dataframe.

So far I have 2 code snippets I have tried but none work properly:

snippet 1 - Using lambdas:

```
def findMake(model):
i_count = 0
for index, row in makes.iterrows():
    found = model.find(makes['makes'][index])
    if found == 0:
        models.set_value(i_count, 'make', makes['makes'][index])
        print index
    i_count+=1

models['models'].map(findMake)
```

snippet 2 - Using 2 for loops:

```
i_count=0
for models_index, row in models.iterrows():
   for makes_index, row_2 in makes.iterrows():
      found = str(row['models'].find(row_2['makes']))
      if found == 0:
        models.set_value(models_index, 'make', makes['makes'][makes_index])
i_count+=1
```

This is the out put when I run findMake

```
    **models**              **make**
    BMW 3 series            BMW
    BMW 5 series            Tata
    Mercedes-Benz E-class   Mercedes-Benz
    Tata 101                None
    Mercedes-Benz C-Class   None
    Tata 208                None
```

however this is what I expect

```
    **models**              **make**
    BMW 3 series            BMW
    BMW 5 series            BMW
    Mercedes-Benz E-class   Mercedes-Benz
    Tata 101                Tata
    Mercedes-Benz C-Class   Mercedes-Benz
    Tata 208                Tata
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looping over `makes` we can get the `Series`' containing each
of the makers from `models`. Then we just insert the maker in the 'makes' `Series` of the found models.

```
for _, maker in makes.iterrows():
    contains_maker = models.models.str.contains(maker.makes)
    models.loc[contains_maker,('makes', )] = maker.makes
```

More info on why `.loc` was used [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Comment: Perfect. This solution gives me the result I need. See here: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/imgs.my.python/solution_found.png

Comment: @Sevanti can you please walk me through why my approach was wrong?

Comment: I think your second snippet might work if you leave out the string conversion before the `found == 0` comparison.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `makes` as a list instead of as a `DataFrame`?

So this is what I did,

1) Define a list containing all the makes:

```
makes = ["BMW", "Tata", "Mercedes-Benz"]
```

2) Define a transformation function:

```
def apply_label(row):
    for makes_name in makes:
        if makes_name in row['models']:
            return makes_name
    return "Not in the list"
```

3) Use the [`apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to transform the rows. Note that I assume `models` is the second data-frame with the headers `['models', 'make']` you are referring to.

```
models['make'] = models.apply(lambda row: apply_label(row), axis=1)
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Very pythonic solution. I'll consider converting the df to a list in the future. Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [68]: df['makes'] = df.models.str.split('\s+', expand=True) \
                         .applymap(lambda x:
                                   x if x in makes['makes'].tolist()
                                   else '') \
                         .sum(axi=1)
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
                  models          makes
0           BMW 3 series            BMW
1           BMW 5 series            BMW
2  Mercedes-Benz E-class  Mercedes-Benz
3               Tata 101           Tata
4  Mercedes-Benz C-Class  Mercedes-Benz
5               Tata 208           Tata
6            Cool BMW X5            BMW
```

In this particular case you can get the make from the model name:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
                  models
0           BMW 3 series
1           BMW 5 series
2  Mercedes-Benz E-class
3               Tata 101
4  Mercedes-Benz C-Class
5               Tata 208

In [36]: makes
Out[36]:
           makes
0            BMW
1           Tata
2  Mercedes-Benz

In [37]: df['makes'] = df.models.str.extract(r'(?P<m1>[^\s]*)\s*')

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
                  models          makes
0           BMW 3 series            BMW
1           BMW 5 series            BMW
2  Mercedes-Benz E-class  Mercedes-Benz
3               Tata 101           Tata
4  Mercedes-Benz C-Class  Mercedes-Benz
5               Tata 208           Tata
```

Comment: The problem with a regular expression like this is that it breaks down in conditions when the car make has 2 separate words, like Alfa Romeo. See here: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/imgs.my.python/alfa+romeo.png

Comment: @xupv5, yes it'll be a problem if you will have makes in your `makes` DF with two or more words.